# Looking for compherensive diet program that is utilizing AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I Am looking for compherensive program to organize ones diet, that is powered by AI.

Unfortunately I looked extensively and didn't find anything on market, all are very bad: one for 12.99$ monthly doesn't track even micronutrients. I am struggling to find anything - looked really long time!

I need following features:

1. be able to track micronutrients
2. be able to add custom foods/meals and their nutritional profile, even create new nutrients if programs don't track these by default
3. be able to veto foods either from meals of day (breakfast, lunch) ahead prior to generation, and later be able to re-generate any meal, or replace it manually by my food i added to the app

I might forgot something i suffer from severe chronic pain, thanks for understanding! This is life or death to me!

**Not to mention: program has to be highly customizable/flexible/compherensive, even if it costs more...** Mainly so it works and it is doesn't look like something what 2nd year student of college written in couple weeks... All i found look like simple cash grab...

Comment: What platform should it run on? Windows? Mac? Linux? Android? Ios? Other?

Answer (score 1):

MyFitenessPal is generally held to be excellent and seems to do what you want.

It doesn't have an AI label yet, but probably will soon. As will my Corn Flakes and hairbrush, no doubt.

I mean no offence, but why are you chasing this year's buzzword? All programming is, arguably, AI. And a lot of Apps are going to slap that label on, just to boost sales.

Why not just find an app that does what you want?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myfitnesspal.android&hl=en_US&gl=US

> SO MUCH MORE THAN A CALORIE COUNTER & DIET JOURNAL
>
> The leading health and nutrition app is like having a fitness tracker,
> macros counter, diet planner, and nutrition coach at your fingertips.
>
> ■ Log Food – Easy-to-use planner tools that make food tracking quick
> and simple
> ■ Track Activity – Add workouts and steps with the fitness
> tracker and planner
> ■ Customize Your Fitness Goals – Weight loss,
> weight gain, weight maintenance, nutrition & fitness
> ■ See Your
> Fitness Progress – Track at a glance, or analyze your diet & macros in
> detail
> ■ Learn From a Registered Dietitian – Meal Plans customized for
> your target calories and macros, whether you’re into weight loss or
> weight gain — with access to our Meal Planner, macro tracker, and
> Calorie Counter tools
> ■ Stay Inspired – 500+ healthy recipes for a
> healthy diet and 50 workouts keep routines fresh and fun
> ■ Connect
> With Community – Find friends and motivation in our active
> MyFitnessPal forums

I am told that it also lets you scan barcodes to input nutritional information.